# Can't access WebHDFS using Big Data Europe with docker-compose

Tags: docker, hadoop, docker-compose, webhdfs

I can't access WebHDFS via Curl or using Python HDFS when using the Big Data Europe 2020 Hadoop Cluster via docker-compose (https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/). For instance, the response of  `curl -i "http://localhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/user/?op=GETFILESTATUS"` is `curl: (52) Empty reply from server`.

When I log into the namenode and check to see if port 50070 is in use, all I can see is that ports 9000 and 9870 are being used, and the 50070 and 50075 are not.

I've double checked to ensure that  `HDFS_CONF_dfs_webhdfs_enabled=true` is also set across the board. This carries through and is accurately set in the config files as expected.

Any suggestions on what could be keeping WebHDFS from working properly?

(I have also posted this as an issue at https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/issues/96).

Comment: Port 50070 isn't exposed to your host https://github.com/big-data-europe/docker-hadoop/blob/master/docker-compose.yml#L8

Comment: Sorry that I didn't include the entire docker-compose.yml. The namenode exposes the following ports:

ports:
      - 9870:9870
      - 9000:9000
      - 50070:50070
      - 50075:50075